# Cursor to fill data in table?

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_A](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [AREA] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Year] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Month] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Factor] [float] NULL,
        [Net] [float] NULL,
        [Path] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [Created] [smalldatetime] NULL,
        [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [LastModified] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)
    )

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_A] ADD  DEFAULT ((1.0)) FOR [Factor]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_A] ADD  DEFAULT (sysdatetime()) FOR [Created]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_A] ADD  DEFAULT (suser_name()) FOR [CreatedBy]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_A] ADD  DEFAULT (sysdatetime()) FOR [LastModified]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_A] ADD  DEFAULT (suser_name()) FOR [LastModifiedBy]
GO
```

I need to fill up the Table using cursor where 
cursor should fetch data from 
Declare Cur_AREA Cursor
            For

```
Select Distinct Media From DIM_AREA
```

Note:DIM_AREA CONSISTS OF texas,dallas,chicago and newark.
  Cursor should fill data for years 1990 to 2020

My cursor code is::

```
Declare @Temp_Year int
        Select @Temp_Year = MAX(Year) 
        While @Temp_Year < DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
        Begin

Declare Cur_Media Cursor
            For 
            Select Distinct Media From DIM_AREA
            Order by Media
            open Cur_Media
            Fetch Next From Cur_Media
            While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            Begin
            Declare @Temp_Month int
                Set @Temp_Month = 1

                While @Temp_Month <= 12
                Begin
                    Insert into Table_A (Media, Year, month)

                    Set @Temp_Month = @Temp_Month + 1
                    Set @Temp_Year = @Temp_Year + 1
                    end
                    end
                    Close Cur_Media
            Deallocate Cur_Media
```

But my cursor not working properly :(

Comment: Great!  What does the code that you've tried look like?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to print my Cursor Code...

Comment: Well AREA requires a value, for starters, and you haven't set a default or supplied a value. Usually "not working" is easier to diagnose when you include an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You may have other problems here, I don't think your question is fleshed out, but you say:

```
Insert into Table_A (Media, Year, month)
```

But you don't pick anything to be inserted.

Use:

```
Insert into Table_A (Media, Year, month)
VALUES('','','')
```

or:

```
Insert into Table_A (Media, Year, month)
SELECT '','',''
FROM YourTable
```

Replacing the empty quotes with whatever you are trying to insert.